# Converting avi to mov (pro res format) using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and I'm trying to convert an .avi into a .mov in pro res format.

What I have so far is this:

```
ffmpeg -probesize 5000000 -r 25 -i movie.avi -r 25 -codec:v prores \
-profile:v 3 -codec:a pcm_s16le -filter_complex asetnsamples=n=16384:p=0 movie.mov
```

The movie is less than a minute long and is 1920x1080. The audio is 16 bit stereo, 44kHz and runs at 25 fps.  I just want to make sure I've got all the the parameters right, that's all. Thank you.
This is what the console pops out:

```
ffmpeg -probesize 5000000 -r 25 -i D:\movie.avi -r 25 -codec:v prores -profile:v 3
odec:a pcm_s16le -filter_complex asetnsamples=n=16384:p=0 movie.mov
ffmpeg version N-55515-gbbbd959 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 13 2013 18:01:31 with gcc 4.7.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r
enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --e
ble-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-li
tmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libv
amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 42.100 / 52. 42.100
  libavcodec     55. 27.100 / 55. 27.100
  libavformat    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavdevice    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
  libavfilter     3. 82.100 /  3. 82.100
  libswscale      2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libswresample   0. 17.103 /  0. 17.103
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[avi @ 02947c80] non-interleaved AVI
[avi @ 02947c80] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
[avi @ 02947c80] Stream #1: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : stereo
Input #0, avi, from 'D:\movie.avi':
  Duration: 00:00:29.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1245583 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 1920x1080, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, mov, to 'movie.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.13.102
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: prores (apch) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s16le) -> asetnsamples (graph 0)
  asetnsamples (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s16le)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo -> prores)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  727 fps= 11 q=0.0 Lsize=  757331kB time=00:00:29.08 bitrate=213344.4kbits/s
video:752314kB audio:5009kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.000950%
```

Comment: Please always also include the complete ffmpeg console output from your ffmpeg command.

Comment: Looks ok, although normally the frame rate (`-r`) is specified in the container and you shouldn't need to change it.  You shouldn't need to set the number of samples per audio packet either.  What is the issue that you are encountering?

Comment: I've added the console output. With the above command I wasn't getting any errors - just the Stream  #0/1: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize. Initially I was getting errors when converting an Xvid avi; so I changed the source avi to uncompressed. I'm really after peace of mind that those paramater will get me a pro res movie, that's all. It plays back fine on a mac.